# How to set dynamically JTable's width in ScrollPane in JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jinternalframe

I have a little doubt using JTable.

This is that I want:

- To set a horizontal ScroollBar in my JTable with no maximized window.
- To see each column with the max width possible (or column header or text in cell).
- Expand dinamically my window depending of JTable's width (I don't know if it is possible).

This is that I have:

- A Jtable with no horizontal ScrollBar (if i put "myTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);", my table doesn't occupy all width of JInternalFrame)
- My Jtable doesn't show all datas in a cell if its size is long.

I will appreciate any help.

AplicacionesInternalFrame:

```
public AplicacionesJInternalFrame() 
{
      super("Aplicaciones", 
              true, //resizable
              true, //closable
              true, //maximizable
              true);//iconifiable

      //...Create the GUI and put it in the window...

      //...Then set the window size or call pack...
      //setSize(300,300);

      //Set the window's location.
      setLocation(xOffset*openFrameCount, yOffset*openFrameCount);
      getContentPane().add(createToolBar(),BorderLayout.NORTH);

      jTableAplicaciones = new JTable(new AplicacionesTableModel());        
      jTableAplicaciones.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new AplicacionesRenderer());
      jTableAplicaciones.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 270));
      jTableAplicaciones.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTableAplicaciones);
      scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED); 
      scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

      initColumnSizes(jTableAplicaciones);
      //jTableAplicaciones.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

      add(scrollPane);        
      pack();
}


private void initColumnSizes(JTable table) {
    TableColumn column = null;
    Component comp = null;
    int headerWidth = 0;
    TableCellRenderer headerRenderer =
        table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();

    int width = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) 
    {           
        /* Tamaño dato de celda */
        TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(0, i);
        Component componente = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, 0, i);
        int componenteWidth = componente.getPreferredSize().width;

        /* Tamaño cabecera columna */
        column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        comp = headerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                null, column.getHeaderValue(),
                false, false, 0, 0);            
        headerWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;
        column.setPreferredWidth(Math.max(headerWidth, componenteWidth)+2);
    }        
}
```

If you need any other data, please let me know it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> My Jtable doesn't show all datas in a cell if its size is long.

You can use the [Table Column Adjuster](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) to make sure all columns are an appropriate. However, this will not force the table to fill the entire width.